# How to prevent location-based page redirection.

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, geolocation, address-bar

I am trying to access the site https://www.uspoloassn.com/ but redirect me to http://la.uspoloassn.com/ (I'm from Mexico). I have tried using different browsers, deleting cookies and using a VPN as an extension of Chrome.

How to prevent such redirections and see the original site that I want to access?

Comment: Have you tried the Tor Browser, https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en?

Comment: You will need an actual vpn service, then you can pick your location of the server you wish to exit in any country....https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/how-it-works/

Comment: I wonder if the site is redirecting based on language reported by the browser - in which case, a plugin to allow the browser to negotiate in English might help?  Failing which, using a VPN terminated in USA, and/or using a Nameserver based in USA should do you.